# Rails: validation fails with before_create method on datetime attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

```
ApiKey.create!
```

Throws a validation error: expires_at can't be blank.

```
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create     :set_expires_at

  validates :expires_at, presence: true

  private

  def set_expires_at
    self.expires_at = Time.now.utc + 10.days
  end
end
```

with attribute

```
t.datetime :expires_at
```

However, if the validation is removed the before_create method works on create.

Why is this? - This pattern works for other attributes, e.g. access_tokens (string), etc.

Answer (score 12):

I would say because the `before_create` runs after the validation, maybe you want to replace `before_create` with `before_validation`

**Note:** If you leave the call back like that, it would set the expiry date whenever you run `valid?` or `save` or any active record method that fires the validation, You might want to limit this validation to the creation process only

```
before_validation :set_expires_at, on: :create
```

This will limit the function call only when the creation is run first time.